# Binding between threads and between managed and unmanaged code

Tags: c#, c++, function-pointers, shared-memory

I have a C++ dll (specifically a directshow filter) which is being used in a 3rd party program. I am controlling it with a C# program via shared memory (so MemoryMappedFile on the C# side, and CreateFileMapping on C++).

**So to be clear: There is not 1 program. It is 2 different programs running at once, and I want the unmanaged code (C++) program to invoke a method in the managed code program (C#)**

The memory sharing works fine. I can use the C# program to change and check values as the 3rd party program uses the dll.

The problem is that I want to effectively databind some aspect of my C# program to a value in the C++ dll. That is, when ever the value is changed in the dll being used by the 3rd party program, I want it to automagically update in the C# program.

Now I can certainly just poll the value every second in another thread of my C# program. But what I would like is to have my dll call a PropertyChangedEventHandler in C#. Or at least call a method that invokes it.

My first approach was to pass a delegate of a C# method through an IntPtr via the shared memory.

So the C++ looks at the shared memory and it sees a struct like so

```
struct MyStruct
{
    //...some ints, etc
    int (*ptr2Func)(int); //not sure if I need to change this to a void pointer, but then how do I cast it to a function pointer in my C++?
    //...etc
}
```

my C# code looks at the shared memory and sees

```
struct MyStruct
{
    //...the same ints as in the C++
    public IntPtr ptr2Func;
    //etc..
}
```

As I said, all the other values in the shared memory struct work fine and I can manually check to see or modify values.

When the C++ dll's main process is initialized, it sets the ptr2Func to NULL. It then makes sure it's not NULL before it tries to execute it.

The C# then sets it to a local method:

```
unsafe public delegate int mydelegate(int input);
public myDelegate tempDele;
public int funcToBeCalled(int input)
{
        return (2);
}

// this code is inside a button click method right after it connects the C# program to the shared memory:
tempDele = this.funcToBeCalled;
sharedInstanceOfMyStruct->pt2Func = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(tempDele);
```

The 3rd party program is fine until the function pointer in the struct is changed from being NULL and the code in the DLL tries to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think you can do this, basically. The two processes are running in a different adress space. The adress that you store in your shared memory does point to a function in the C# process, but it does not point to code the calling process. It will just crash.

You can use WCF, named pipes or sockets to send a trigger message to the other application.

Comment: You might also use a named Event to signal (cheaper than pipes or sockets if you don't have to pass data)

Comment: @Tergiver: that's probably cheaper. I just hate the windows API for events. It appears to presume some CS course on OS synchronization primitives that everybody took but me.

Comment: Ah that makes sense why it doesn't work. Thanks for the ideas on how to send the trigger message, I'll look into each of the ones you both listed